# Go(lang) with nginx - Serving Static Files

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Currently I have the following HTTP server written in Go:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(response, request, "/var/www/default/htdocs/index.html")
    })

    http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/var/www/default/htdocs/public"))))

    http.HandleFunc("/json", func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        // serves a JSON response
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/socket", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // replies to the WebSocket
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

I've seen some benchmarks that show that nginx can serve a lot more requests per second when it comes to static files. Another useful feature of nginx is that it can gzip responses transparently and even serve pre-compressed files with the [`gzip_static` module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipStaticModule).

Ideally, I want nginx to serve all existing (static) files and proxy everything that doesn't exist to Go:

```
location / {
    try_files               $uri $uri/ @go;
}

location @go {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
}
```

Unfortunatly, nginx doesn't like the above configuration:

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by
>   regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if"
>   statement, or inside "limit_except" block in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:23

At this point, I know I have several options:

**1) put `proxy_pass` in the `location /` block**

But this will proxy everything, even the existing (static) files.

**2) write individual `/json` and `/socket` location blocks in nginx**

But if I want to add more handlers in Go, I also have to update the nginx vhost accordingly.

**3) rewrite the Go code and use `fastcgi_pass` in nginx instead of `proxy_pass`**

```
location @go {
    fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

I would also have to change the Go code to use `net/http/fcgi` instead of `net/http`, the problem with this is that I don't know how to specify the paths (`/json` or `/socket`) with [`fcgi.Serve()`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/fcgi/child.go?s=6606:6660#L262).

Additionally, FastCGI seems to be 4 times slower than HTTP: https://gist.github.com/hgfischer/7965620.

**4) discard nginx altogether**

Make Go serve everything (including static files) and handle gzip compression on every request.

---

**How can I make nginx and Go to behave like I want (preferably with the HTTP interface)?**

*Apologies if this question is too basic, this is my very first experience writing a Go web app.*

### Additional Question

In PHP, I point `fastcgi_pass` to the `php-fpm` Unix socket. If any request experiences a *PHP fatal error*, the upcoming requests will still be served. However, if my Go code calls `panic()` the program will be terminated and the service will stop responding. What is the best way to handle that in Go?

Comment: I've been looking at go for all of two hours, but would it be helpful to use the concurrency and channels (prefix some of those with the 'go ' keyword) for parallelization?

Comment: @gWaldo If your task is parallel in nature, then yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with  "proxy_pass" seems to be because of trailing `/`, try to remove it, as it does nothing any way. If you need to alter URI before passing it to proxy, try to use rewrite, i.e to remove some part of URI try something like:

```
location @go {
    rewrite           ^/part_to_remove(/.*)$ $1;
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following nginx config - [resource](http://nginx.com/admin-guide/serving-static-content/)

```
server {
  server_name _;
  root /home/vagrant/htdocs/sinatra-test;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4567;
  }
}
```

Below is my directory structure:

```
/home/vagrant/htdocs/sinatra-test
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- app.rb
`-- assets
    `-- css
        `-- screen.css
```

According to [this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) site I run a simple sinatra app:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

And that are the responses

```
# logged in the sinatra log
$ curl localhost/hi
Hello World!

# not logged in the sinatra log - comes directly from nginx
$ curl localhost/assets/css/screen.css
body { background: red; }

# logged in the sinatra log
$ curl localhost/test
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body { text-align:center;font-family:helvetica,arial;font-size:22px;
    color:#888;margin:20px}
  #c {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:left}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Sinatra doesn&rsquo;t know this ditty.</h2>
  <img src='http://localhost:4567/__sinatra__/404.png'>
  <div id="c">
    Try this:
    <pre>get '/test' do
  "Hello World"
end
</pre>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As You can see if the file does not exist the request goes to the the sinatra app.

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
```